# Does 連続性 have a different meaning than just "continuity"?

Tags: meaning, words

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YD_Z6QHD1Dg

I've noticed that usually words have other meanings than just the standard definitions that dictionaries give. I bet 連続性 probably means something different than what every dictionary gives:

1. continuity Mathematics

I ran this sentence through Google Translate. It's part of a video and it's a cut-off sentence since this is from someone speaking and it's here where the audio starts.

As you can see, the machine translation makes little to no sense anyway, leaving further doubt.

> 、かつその連続性で手になじむものじゃないと遊んでくれないから、やっぱそれがすごい大きいですよね。
> *And, if it's not something that fits in your hand because of its continuity, it won't play, so it's really big.*

Comment: Do you have a timestamp for your video?

Comment: Oh hi! Yeah its the first sentence of the video 00:00. The guy in the glasses.

Comment: Please provide more contexts. He seems to describe tactile, so it may mean smoothness of texture. But I am not so sure…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's said right after かつ, so he is probably saying "as a continuation (of the first reason not included in the video)" or "by extension". その連続性で is not a common wording, and I usually expect それと関連して, それ繋がりで, その関連で, etc. Outside math contexts, 連続性がある may simply mean *closely related*.

> …かつ、その連続性で、手になじむものじゃないと遊んでくれないから...
>
> ...and, by extension, people don't play it unless it doesn't feel good in the hands, so...